# store a Byte[] in an sqlite db in small chunks?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, byte

I would like to store a large `Byte[]` in my SQLite database.

Android has a limit to how much RAM each app can use, so I figured the best way to skirt around this limitation is to write the file in smaller chunks.

Is it possible to use a stream to access my file, and append to my database `Byte[]` in small pieces?  (without loading the `Byte[]` into memory to append)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data in files in your app/sdcard and keep a reference in SQLite - you cannot append to BLOBs in SQLite (at least without pre-allocating the size with zeroblob() and using the NDK) - besides - how would you read it back? The only API made available in the SDK will attempt to read the entire BLOB back as a `byte[]`.

Typically you want to implement `ContentProvider#openFile(..)` properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So it sounds like you're saying there is no way to read/write to the db using a stream.  I will look into the ContentProvider class, and see if any ideas click.  Thanks

Comment: No good way at least, especially for huge binary blogs - you can do read/write/append through the standard ContentResolver API if you implement a ContentProvider#openFile(..) method. Unfortunately it works best (least amount of hacks to get at hidden functionality) to store the data exchanged with openFile(..) in a file in your app folder or SDcard.

Comment: Oh ok.  Well maybe an SQLite db isn't the ideal solution for storage.  Is there a better format, if I wanted to store 5 large files, but wanted them to reside within a single file?  I saw an iOS post talking about file "bundles", is there something similar in Android, that I could stream/append to?